# Ableton Live 10 w/ Push 2: Play notes while a clip is looping during global recording

Tags: ableton-live

I am trying to record a live performance on Push 2.

I start global recording in the arrangement view and then start my performance in the session view.
I record some notes into a clip, and now it's looping.
Now I want to play some random notes on the same instrument (that should not be recorded), while the same clip is still looping.
The global recording seems to disarm the instrument after recording a clip, and I can only play notes whilst recording into the same clip.
Could somebody explain to me how I could achieve the above ? Many thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, in Live 9, there is a separate button for MIDI overdub. It switches the recording into session slots on/off. There are certain pre-conditions: the track must be armed; the track must be in "auto" monitoring mode. I should thing that Live 10 behaves similarly.